# Set title and (title) icon for a custom alert dialog

Tags: android, title, android-alertdialog, customdialog

I don't manage to set a neither a title nor a (title) icon to my custom alert dialog. 
My code:

```
public class AddingFavoriteDialog extends AlertDialog {
private OnAddingFavoriteListener       onAddingFavoriteListener;
private Context context;
private GeocodingManager geocodingManager;
private FavoritesActivity favoritesActivity;

public AddingFavoriteDialog(Context context, OnAddingFavoriteListener onAddingFavoriteListener) {
 super(context, android.R.style.Theme_Dialog);

this.context = context;
this.onAddingFavoriteListener = onAddingFavoriteListener;
this.geocodingManager = new GeocodingManager(context);
this.favoritesActivity = (FavoritesActivity) context;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 setContentView(R.layout.adding_favorite_dialog2);

 setTitle("MYTITLE");

 setIcon(R.drawable.star_gold);
 }
```

What am i doing wrong? I also tried to set it by calling `super.setTitle("MYTITLE");` in `onCreate()` as well as in the constructor.

**EDIT:** Even `setButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE, context.getString(R.string.button_value_OK),
                new OnClickListener() {...}` seems not to work.

Comment: try using this.setTtitle(""); or if that doesnt work Classname.steTitle("");

Comment: How are you instantiating the dialog?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`setView`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setView%28android.view.View%29) instead of `setContentView`, because `setContentView` replaces everything in the `AlertDialog`, including the default title bar and icon (and buttons etc.). Instead, `setView` only replaces the middle part (the message, if you will).

Use [`LayoutInflater`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) if you need to.

Comment: Ok, this seems to be right. But not, if I try to `findViewById()` it doesn't recognizes any of my Views.

Comment: Inflating your layout using `LayoutInflater` will give you a `View` object. Use `findViewById()` on that object, not on the AlertDialog itself. Let us know if that works.

Comment: Even though I pretty sure, I've tried this some hours ago... guess what: No errors any more. But also no dialog anymore. ;) Theres just a plain dialog window, without any content, title or anything else.

Comment: Sounds counter intuitive... I would expect the content view to be the middle part.

Answer (score 0):

Extending Dialog instead of AlertDialog will fix the problem.