# AlertDialog with custom content view looks nothing like AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I have a custom subclass of AlertDialog that should display a list of all the available Wifi networks in range.

I'm displaying this dialog by creating an instance of it, and calling show(), and **I'm not using AlertDialog.Builder** (Because I want my custom class to be used).

I have my own layout to display as the content view, but I want the regular AlertDialog look and feel, with the title header and the frame.

My custom layout is pretty simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

And I'm adding it to the dialog at onCreate():

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTitle(R.string.pick_wifi_network);
    setContentView(R.layout.pick_wifi_dialog);
    // Rest of implementation
}
```

But the result look nothing like AlertDialog. There is no title, and the ListView takes the whole screen:

[image]

So what am I doing wrong and how should I do it right?

Thanks!

**Edit:**
Why I don't use AlertDialog.Builder: My custom Dialog class is responsible for listening for SCAN_RESULTS_AVALIABLE_ACTION of WifiManager, and updating the ListView as results refreshes. For this reason I cannot use AlertDialog.Builder.
**END EDIT**

Comment: If all you want is the default look of an `AlertDialog` but with a list, I don't understand why you don't just use `AlertDialog.Builder` and call `setItems(...)`. It will create a list for you.

Comment: Also, you can use `setView()` method in `AlertDialog.Builder` to pass a custom layout.

Comment: I'm editing my question to answer both of you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is in the dialog's theme (which you're not applying).

I haven't tried this, but if I understand it correctly, it should work:

In your dialog's constructor, call the super constructor wich receives a theme, passing the standard dialog theme.

```
public CustomDialog(Context context) {
    super(context, android.R.style.Theme_Dialog);
}
```

The dialogs created in Android have this default theme.

The documentation for the Theme_Dialog states (v2.2):

> Default theme for dialog windows and activities (on API level 10 and
>   lower), which is used by the Dialog class. This changes the window to
>   be floating (not fill the entire screen), and puts a frame around its
>   contents. You can set this theme on an activity if you would like to
>   make an activity that looks like a Dialog.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:**

To solve the problem with `setTitle`, the easiest way seems to be inheriting `Dialog` instead of `AlertDialog`.

Also doing that, there is no need to pass the `android.R.style.Theme_Dialog` in the constructor (aparently subclassing `AlertDialog` comes with no theme).

Comment: OK!! It definetley helps! now the list is inside a floating frame as it should, but still no title though... any idea about that?

Comment: I ended testing it by myself, and saw the issue with `setTitle`. There are a couple of related questions about this, being the most useful [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712331/set-title-and-title-icon-for-a-custom-alert-dialog).